# how do i make a namespace for math formula

Tags: c++, namespaces

[I want to calculate the space of the circle
but after i enter the value of r  the value of x become 0]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjgpH.png) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaRWI.png)

I did not try anything since I am a beginner

Comment: After you enter the value of `r`, `x` was already `0` and hasn't been changed after entering the value of `r`.

Comment: Your code is using the wrong approach, you need to write **functions** not namespaces. Since you are a beginner you need to read a [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282) that will explain the basics of the language. You cannot learn C++ by asking questions here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the proper usage to `namespace`. We use such language feature in case we want to generate a space with our own functions and variables, similar to classes. I recommend you to create a function with desired behaviour.

Comment: i know but i have a home work and the teacher said that we must use namespace

Comment: In this case, @Mason Raza posted the answer you wish

Answer (score 1):

you are not returning anything in your namespace.. check this code:

```
// Creating namespaces
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace mc {
const float b = 3.14;
float value(int r) { 
    return b*r*r; 
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    int r;
    cin>>r;
    cout << mc::value(2) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Please mark this answer correct if you are satisfied with this.